# Any ideas to creating a "password tab"?

Tags: apache, web, drupal, passwords, user-experience

This inquiry is quite ambiguous so let me try my best to clarify. I want to create a link on a webpage containing confidential samples that when a user clicks, opens a tab and requires the user to input a password in order to access the information.

Any help or word of advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This isn't really a question.  An observation is that tabs are generally loaded with the page and hidden.  In your case the tab contents will have to be retrieved via AJAX only after the credentials have been entered.  But, that aside, what's your question?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll try to be as clear as possible. 

How would I go about creating a link that contains confidential information specific to the user and when clicked, it would open up a tab that requires authorization in order to access the information. 

I've been given advice to use Apache and Drupal but I'm not sure how to start things.